# How to display the result of a formula in a tkinter Entry textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I`'m building a GUI for an engineering software that I've created and, being a beginner on Python, I'm having trouble with the code. I'll try to simplify my problem and describe what I want to do:

Using Python and Tkinter, I want to create a simple window with 3 Entry widgets. The first two will be my inputs. The third one, the output, should display the sum of whatever numbers are inserted in the first two. The output value should refresh as soon as I insert any values in the inputs and should not be changeable in any other way (disabled or read-only, I guess). I intend to use the output value in other calculation forward in the project.

Thanks in advance for helping!

This is the initial look of the window. Tried a lot of different methods, but none of then worked so far.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Simple window")

window_frame = tk.LabelFrame(window)
window_frame.pack()

input1_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="input 1")
input1_label.pack()
input1_entry= tk.Entry(window_frame)
input1_entry.pack()

input2_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="input 2")
input2_label.pack()
input2_entry= tk.Entry(window_frame)
input2_entry.pack()

output_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="output")
output_label.pack()
output_entry= tk.Entry(window_frame)
output_entry.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to have a button that lets the user say "Go".  You'll add a `command` parameter to specify a callback that will get called when the button is clicked.  That callback will do the computation and set the result in the output window.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I know how to do it with a button, but for the project I`m working in I wanted to do it without it. Is that possible?

Comment: SOMETHING has to trigger the computation.  You can add a `command` to the entry boxes, but that will get called every time any key is typed in either box.  You would have to do error checking to make sure (a) both boxes have values, and (b) neither box has garbage data.

Comment: @JohnEngineer You could bind to a keyboard event like `'<KeyPress>'` or `'<KeyRelease>'` to have the result calculated as the input `Entry` widgets are being edited, but that could result in erroneous results while the user is still typing. Alternatively, you could bind to `'<FocusOut>'` on the second (or both) `Entry` widget(s) to trigger the calculation when the user leaves the field. That said, I would argue that both options are bad UX as they violate the ["Principle of Least Astonishment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), which is to say, just use a button!

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried the "command" thing, but with no success. Maybe I did it the wrong way.

@JRiggles How does the "Focus thing" works? Don`t make me use a Button =(

Comment: @JohnEngineer Can I at least ask why you're anti-button before I teach you bad UX? ;)

Comment: @JRiggles is right.  A button is what people expect.  They expect to be able to "compose" their inputs without interference, then press a big "DO IT" button.

Comment: @JRiggles The output value is a very simple calculation, and is supposed to be another parameter for a much bigger computation (engineering stuff). I'm definitely setting a button for the big thing, but setting a button for this minor calculation will feel like an unnecessary step in the big picture (the actual project should have other parameters like that). Besides, in some already available engineering software it is a common practice. That's why I thought it would be simple. I was expecting the Entry widget to function like an Excel cell...

Comment: If it turns out to be that much more complicated, I'm considering simply not showing the minor parameters (before the big computation) in the window. But it would be nice to see those parameters before the "gran finale" ; (

Comment: @JohnEngineer that makes sense, and UX design doesn't come with a lot of *hard* rules - just make sure your users know what's happening and why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it *without* a button (with apologies to @TimRoberts).

> ##### Pro Tip: don't do this.

```
import tkinter as tk


def compute():
    x1 = input1_entry.get()
    x2 = input2_entry.get()
    sumx = int(x1)+int(x2)
    output_entry.configure(text=str(sumx))


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Simple window")

window_frame = tk.LabelFrame(window)
window_frame.pack()

input1_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="input 1")
input1_label.pack()
input1_entry= tk.Entry(window_frame)
input1_entry.pack()

input2_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="input 2")
input2_label.pack()
input2_entry= tk.Entry(window_frame)
input2_entry.pack()

# bind this event to the Entry so 'compute' is called when the user exits the field
# (I used a lambda here so the unused 'event' value is simply discarded since
# 'compute' doesn't need it)
input1_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda _event: compute())
input2_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda _event: compute())

output_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="output")
output_label.pack()
output_entry= tk.Label(window_frame)
output_entry.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"don't do this."_: Why?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria see my comment above re: the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). It's not that this *won't* work, it's just not what people are used to.

Comment: @JRiggles It worked!! I changed the "input2.bind" to "input2_entry.bind" and did the same to "input1_entry.bind" and it is working as I expected! Thank you a lot! But I noticed the output_entry is looking like a Label...

Comment: @JohnEngineer Glad I could help. If this worked for you, please accept this answer so other folks know this question has been answered.

Comment: @JRiggles Applyed it to the actual project and it worked! Thank you! Will try a different approach later with an "entry.insert" instead of the "entry.configure".  Appreciate the patience with this anti-button engineer!!

Comment: Good to hear! And no worries, I don't mean to give ya a hard time - just passing along what I know. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to do it with a button.  Note that I changed the output to a Label to make it read-only:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Simple window")

window_frame = tk.LabelFrame(window)
window_frame.pack()

input1_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="input 1")
input1_label.pack()
input1_entry= tk.Entry(window_frame)
input1_entry.pack()

input2_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="input 2")
input2_label.pack()
input2_entry= tk.Entry(window_frame)
input2_entry.pack()

output_label= tk.Label(window_frame, text="output")
output_label.pack()
output_entry= tk.Label(window_frame)
output_entry.pack()

def compute():
    x1 = input1_entry.get()
    x2 = input2_entry.get()
    sumx = int(x1)+int(x2)
    output_entry.configure(text=str(sumx))

go = tk.Button(window_frame, text="Go!", command=compute)
go.pack()

window.mainloop()
```